# HTML: Embedding an img into an a tag into a td element

Tags: html, tags, image

I'm trying to show an image of checker (it's a .png and I've verified the spelling and all) into an a tag into a td element like so:

```
<td id=""  class= "open-square"><a href="/gameplay/A3" ><img source="/img/black_checker.png"></a></td>
```

But the image isn't showing up and the square isn't clickable. Otherwise the checkerboard renders fine, shows the styling associated with the td element. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute to define an image's source is `src`, not `source`.

Comment: Tnanks. Very nube of me. I'm a bit new to client side stuff. I'll stop making excuses now.

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace the `source` attribute with `src`. And keep in mind that the `alt` attribute is required for validation.